# ¿Convertir meses en string a enteros?

Tags: linux, bash, script, unix

Tengo un output de un mes:

```
Agosto
```

Quiero convertirlo a entero:

```
08
```

En linux Bash, tengo el siguiente código... Pero no funciona, ya que me da saltos del linea con cada elemento convertido:

```
com2=$(cut -d/ -f2,2 tmp_date.log | sed -n '1p')
print "$com2" > tmp_date2.log
if [[ "$com2" = "December" ]] then month=12
    elif [[ "$com2" = "November" ]] then month=11
    elif [[ "$com2" = "October" ]] then month=10
    elif [[ "$com2" = "September" ]] then month=09
    elif [[ "$com2" = "August" ]] then month=08
    elif [[ "$com2" = "July" ]] then month=07
    elif [[ "$com2" = "June" ]] then month=06
    elif [[ "$com2" = "May" ]] then month=05
    elif [[ "$com2" = "April" ]] then month=04
    elif [[ "$com2" = "March" ]] then monnth=03
    elif [[ "$com2" = "February" ]] then month=02
    elif [[ "$com2" = "January" ]] then month=01
fi
echo ${month}
```

Hay alguna otra manera de poderlo hacer más eficiente.

Comment: ¿en dónde te _"da" saltos de línea_?, en el stdout? ¿qué salida es la que quieres conseguir exactamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si puedes usar `sed`, aunque no soy un experto, podrías crear múltiples patrones para reemplazar los nombres por los números, algo así:

```
nombre=Agosto
mes=$(sed 's/Enero/01/g; s/Febrero/02/g; s/Marzo/03/g; s/Abril/04/g; s/Mayo/05/g; s/Junio/06/g; s/Julio/07/g; s/Agosto/08/g; s/Septiembre/09/g; s/Octubre/10/g; s/Noviembre/11/g; s/Diciembre/12/g' <<< $nombre)
echo "$nombre es el mes $mes"

Agosto es el mes 08
```

O bien recomiendo un arrays de meses, podríamos obtener el índice:

```
# El indice comienza en 0 por lo que agregamos un Dummy
meses=(Dummy Enero Febrero Marzo Abril Mayo Junio Julio Agosto Septiembre Octubre Noviembre Diciembre)
nombre=Agosto

for i in "${!meses[@]}"; do
   if [[ "${meses[$i]}" = "${nombre}" ]]; then
       mes=${i};
   fi
done

echo "$nombre es el mes $mes"
```

Fuentes: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6744040/6836377) y [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15028821/6836377)

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar printf en lugar de echo, o sea, algo así:

```
printf ${month}
```

Con eso creo que funcionará.

¡Suerte!

Answer (score 0):

Basándose en tu código el salto de línea debe ser porque no añades la bandera `-n` al comando `echo`, es decir, el comando final tendría que ser:

```
echo -n ${month}
```

Ahora si tiene problemas con tu script puedes utilizar el siguiente script:

```
case ${com2} in
    Enero|January) month=01 ;;
    Febrero|February) month=02 ;;
    Marzo|March) month=03 ;;
    Abril|April) month=04 ;;
    Mayo|May) month=05 ;;
    Junio|June) month=06 ;;
    Julio|July) month=07 ;;
    Agosto|August) month=08 ;;
    Septiembre|September) month=09 ;;
    Octubre|October) month=10 ;;
    Noviembre|November) month=11 ;;
    Diciembre|December) month=12 ;;
esac
echo -n ${month}
```

Con la ventaja de que podrías añadir nuevos formatos de mes como oct., Oct, etc.